# How to automatically precompile css.erb file on every request

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In **custom_colors.css.erb** file is:

```
<%
  WebsiteSetting.last.link_color.present? ? (link_color = WebsiteSetting.last.link_color) : (link_color = '#0088cc')
%>
$custom_link: <%= link_color %>;
```

and in many css files i'm using $custom_link variable, but when i update WebsiteSetting.last by setting link_color field by colorpicker (hex), nothing changes in views. I suppose the problem is with precompiling custom_colors.css.erb file after request.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic assets precompilation (on each request) is normally done in development environment only for debugging reasons.

If you want to be able to use some request-dependent styles consider moving that code to the application layout:

**application.html.erb:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <style type="text/css">
      #my_div {
        color: <% WebsiteSetting.last.link_color.present? ? WebsiteSetting.last.link_color : '#0088cc' %>;
      }
    </style>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ... 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But i really need to use $custom_link variable, because i use it in many css files. If i don't, i would have to set color for +/- 50 elements in **application.html.erb** file.

Comment: @kryna I see your concern. You are speaking about SASS variable. SASS is a preprocessor that is compiled into CSS during precompilation and then static assets can be served by Application Server directly. It's impossible to inject something to it.